# Under what set of transliteration rules is кс rendered as the latin x?

Tags: транслитерация

I have followed a couple of different methods (Iso 9 and Passport 2010) and have looked at others which are mentioned on [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian), but no matter what I do, something like the name `Александр` ends up getting rendered in Latin as having `ks` instead of `x`.  I am quite happy with rendering that name as `Aleksandr`, but in the end I need to compare the transliteration with say the way the name is printed in English language newspapers.  I am just wondering where one gets the `x` from?

Comment: This is offtopic here as English language transliteration rules have little to do with Russian language and usage.

Comment: You are wrong. There is a set of rules like GOST R 52535.1-2006, that strictly defines transliteration rules for Russian names and families used for foreign passports. This transliteration based on English form. Prior to 2000s was used another form based on French language (language of international post and document exchange). And Александр Пушкин in old notation would be Aleksandre Pushkine. In new notation it should be Aleksandr Pushkin, but there is no strict control at immigration office and Aleksandr may be written in passport as Alexander or Alexandr, it is up to you.

Comment: Under nothing but author's wish to use `x` instead of `ks`. Some people like to use it, because it's shorter and prettier in some sense.

Answer (score 1):

On the whole, I do not believe there are strict rules about when *кс* should become *x* and when it should become *ks*.  Most of the times, the transliteration will either follow some traditional rules or just be whatever the person writing it decides.

Specifically, Russian name *Александр* and English/Latin name *Alexander* both originate from Greek name *Αλεξανδρος*.  Greek letter *ξ (Xi)* is pronounced as *ks* in Greek.  Because in English (Latin), there's letter *x*, which is pronounced (in most cases) as *ks*, the English writing of the name is more closely conforms to the original Greek writing. In Russian (Cyrillic) there is no such letter, therefore sound combination *ks* has to be indicated by the closest possible way, which is letter combination *кс*.  Thus, comparing transliteration rules from Russian into English in this case isn't particularly useful.

Comment: Is there really an occurrence in English where x is not *ks*?

Comment: @Alenanno As far as I can think, when transliterating from English into Russian, _x_ will always become _кс_ in Russian.  When transliterating from Russian into English, you will sometimes see _кс_ transliterated as _x_ and sometimes as _ks_, often on the same word.

Comment: @Alenanno In some cases, English letter _x_ may correspond to _кз_ in a related Russian word, for example _exam_ is _экзамен_.

Comment: Wait, I think you meant there were ks words in English, not Russian. :)